# Allow user to add labels and textfields

Tags: java, android

I'm making an android database application where I want the user to be able to customize the form layout, really, I'm just trying to make fields hidden at the launch of the application and by user input, changing the layout xml to make fields appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can do with this question is to indicate the developer android site :/

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html